# iOS 10: Storage Almost Full Warning (But I have free space)

Tags: ios, storage

[image]

I am running iOS 10.2.1 on an iPhone 5S, with a doubleH3lix jailbreak. The phone was receiving the "Storage Almost Full" warning before I jailbroke it. I reset the phone to factory settings (got the error after installing one app), jailbroke it, and ran two different cleaning apps, one of which is iCleaner.

I am guessing that whatever cache iCleaner is looking at is the same one causing the warning. But, as you can see, I still have 9GB of free space on this device.

Is there a way to clear this cache and correct the free space showing in iCleaner and stop the warning from being triggered?

Comment: Not knowing diddley about jailbreaking I may be off base here but the usual fix for "where has all my space gone" on an iPhone is to back it up, erase it back to factory specs and then restore from the backup. That usually deletes temp files, caches and defragments available storage.

Comment: @SteveChambers That's part of the reason I'm confused, because it was restored to factory specs and I still got the error. I thought running iCleaner would clear those caches, but it hasn't. (I updated the question to include that).

Comment: Then I am gonna go out on a limb and blame the Jailbreak. If the problem is not there  on a stock phone (not jailbroken)... well you can guess where I'm going.

Comment: @SteveChambers The problem was happening before I jailbroke the phone.

Comment: / is not a cache but is the root partition.  You definitely have something wrong.

Comment: @ThomasNelson I was hoping the problem was a cache of some sort stored in root, mostly because that would be an easier kind of fix.

Comment: @345422 agreed.

Answer (score 1):

I have reset the iPhone from the iPhone's setting (because I did not want to update the phone), but in order to truly clear the caches and space, I had to reset (and update) using iTunes.